# Railsで「.」(ドット)を含んだURLルーティングはどう書きますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

私の `config/routes.rb` は：

```
resources :tags, only: [] do
  resources :blogs, only: [:index]
end
```

もし私「node.js」というタグを作成すれば、URLをアクセスするときに

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/tags/node.js/blogs
```

ルートエラーがありました：

```
No route matches [GET] "/tags/node.js/blogs"
```

どうやってその `.` が識別できますか？

Comment: You can solve this problem by googling with the words, "rails routing dot url".

Comment: @heliac2001 Thank you. I fixed it. Just add `constraints: { id: /.+/ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Railsガイドの[動的なセグメントの章](http://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)の注意書きにもありますが、

> 動的なセグメント分割ではドット.をデフォルトでは使用できません。ドットはフォーマット済みルーティングでは区切り文字として使用されるためです。どうしても動的セグメント内でドットを使用したい場合は、デフォルト設定を上書きする制限を与えます。たとえば`id: /[^\/]+/`とすると、スラッシュ以外のすべての文字が使用できます。

そこで以下の様に制約を追加することで望んだ挙動になるかと思います。

```
resources :tags, only: [], constraints: { id: /[^\/]+/ } do
  resources :blogs, only: [:index]
end
```

Comment: ご回答どうもありがとうございました。